# Android Progress Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, widget

I have a WidgetProvider which is around for milliseconds. It takes in an intent, and it kicks off a service which takes maybe noticeable time. I wanted to display something to the user during this delay like a progress bar that will block user, but the BroadcastReceiver/WidgetProvider seems like the wrong place to start up a progress bar. Where should I issue the Progress Bar in this case?  Service maybe?  but service might not be part of UI at all?

Comment: please clarify for me: do you start the service only to perform one task? Why do you want to show a progress bar for a widget? I suggest to show a "intermediate" state so that the user know that something is processed...

Comment: dont want the user to issue more requests while this service is running.

Comment: i dont get it , the point of running a service is to keep user in the dark, so why is it needed to inform user about delay in completion of service tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I issue the Progress Bar in this case?

From a UI perspective, your only choice is to have it in the app widget itself. ProgressBar is one of the valid widgets to have in an app widget layout.

In terms of who updates the `RemoteViews` of your app widget to display/update/remove the `ProgressBar`, that is probably your `Service` in whatever background thread you are using for the "noticeable time".

Comment: can we change the color of a progress bar in a widget programmatically??

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: You can [use `setProgressDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) to set the `Drawable` used for displaying progress. If you have several such drawables, in different colors, you can switch between them.

Comment: yes, but while setting a progressbar in a widget, there is no such method if I want to set the color of progress bar by a colorCode at run time.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: Ah, my apologies, I was not thinking about app widgets when I wrote my previous comment. The only way I can think of for you to change the color would be to use a different layout resource as the starting point for your `RemoteViews`, where that layout references a different `android:progressDrawable` for your `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a progress bar in the notifications pull down? Doing something like the market displays when you're downloading an app should work really well, and execute in the background well.

Comment: you can do that ? have never thought of it like that

Comment: Yes, the best thing to do is put a progress bar in the notifications window and use an async task to update its progress.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use AsynTask to display progress bar.